# Convert URL to the anchor tag in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I want to convert URL in text to `<a>` as HTML.
The following code causes `<a>` to be escaped in erb.
How do I fix?

index.html.erb

```
<p>
  <%= urlify('Hello https://stackoverflow.com/') %>
  #=> Hello <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">https://stackoverflow.com/</a>
</p>
```

helper.rb

```
require 'uri'

def urlify(text)
  URI.extract(text, ['http', 'https']).uniq.each do |url|
    text = text.gsub!(url, link_to(url, url))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
<p>
  <%= raw(urlify('Hello https://stackoverflow.com/')) %>
</p>
```

Happy Coding :-)